# LED strip Lights stopped working

Tags: led

I purchased 10 LED strip lights from Amazon.  The are 48 inch aluminum body with a stip of LEDs.  They plug directly in to 120 household voltage.  The company says you can link 5 fixtures together.  I sourced power from my garage overhead light and connected 4 fixtures end to end.  I then added another 3 fixtures connected end to end in parallel to the others (same power receptacle).  In my mind I have not exceeded the limit of 5 linked fixtures due to the two branches however some strips have started to die after 6 months of use.  I imagine it is due to my set up but I am not clear as to why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could be they are just cheap.  LEDs can last for a long time, the problem is they require drivers to work and the drivers can fail, either being cheap or overheated.  Should try to find the amps used by each fixture and times that by 7.  Household light circuits are usually 15 amp breaker.  12/13 amps usually pushing it if on for a long time.

Comment: I just measured by cutting one wire in the AC input and it is drawing .37 amps so total circuit should be 2.59 amps.  They were about $10 per light fixture so I guess just cheap components.  I noticed they run 2 wires from the start of the driver to the end of the light to connect the next so the link does not go through the first driver.  Each light gets full 110v.  Perhaps the wire gauge is the limiting factor and it is circuit length that limits it to 5 fixtures.  Still think the 2 branches should have taken care of that.

Comment: I will sometimes purchase no-name LED lighting from Amazon, but have no delusions of quality or longevity on the lights.  Usually they work fine for a while, but (as @crip659 mentioned), probably just cheap components.  Just make sure that anything that plugs in is UL listed (as a lot of Amazon cheap stuff isn't UL listed).  Even then, a lot of the cheap stuff that says it's UL listed is lying about that.  Amazon is the wild-west of electronics purchases, so it's buyer beware, and on a lot of it, no guarantee of quality or safety.

Comment: Most LED strips have an AC to DC power supply, and the actually wiring on the strips is 12 or 24v DC.   There should be enough power in the supply for the rated number of strips., but any sort of short or broken connection can cause the downstream lights to stop working.  If you can check the connectors you might get a better handle on it.

Comment: I have purchased and installed about 30 cheap LED plug-in shop lights from Harbor Freight. Two were DOA, the rest have worked fine for up to 3 years now. Fortunately, they took the two back and exchanged them. I _expect_ cheap from HF, and am happy and excited when things last. If you buy cheap from Amazon, you should expect cheap. Look back at the listing to see if they have any warranty. Contact Amazon to see if you can get a return/replacement.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your setup. The limit of 5 strips is 5 strips connected end to end. There is probably some current limiter/fuse in the plugs that will handle 5 end to end but no more than five. You connecting 4 end to end in one outlet and then 3 end to end in another outlet does not exceed the limit of 5 end to end.

There's a lot of electronics involved in these strips and heat can be a big factor in shortening their life so location should be considered.
Also, as mentioned in many of the comments, cheap components and poor quality control are not uncommon in stuff sold on amazon.

Comment: Turning LEDs on and off thousands of times shouldn't shorten their life (unlike fluorescents).  When LEDs are dimmed using PWM, they are switched on and off thousands of time *per second*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I was thinking more along the lines of the drivers, transformers and capacitors in these strips, not so much the actual bulbs

Comment: When some big name brands sold $40 LED PAR30 bulbs about a decade ago I bought 6 for my kitchen. Though claimed to last for 20+ years at 4 hours/day, all of the ones I bought failed within 5 years.  The multi-decade claims seem greatly exaggerated; at least with mine I kept the receipt and was able to get free replacements under warranty.

Comment: @Armand  I went through the same thing with fluorescent bulbs when they first came out.

Comment: @Armand and if you did an autopsy you would have found the problem wasn't even the LEDs, it was the electronic drivers.  While the LEDs are indestructible *if the heat-sinking is not botched*, the drivers are vulnerable to capacitor disease and other consequences of shortcutting costs to the bare minimum.  I've started to joke that the LEDs don't need sockets, the drivers do!  And in fact some better manufacturers have indulged me.  Conversely I have 12V LED strips made entirely of passives (LED devices and resistors) which have burning 10 years straight 24x7, despite being cheap Chinese.